# PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER - the functions pthread_cond_wait() branch into a slow path

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

From: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/apis/users_75.htm

> Static initialization using the PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER does not immediately initialize the mutex.
>
> Instead, on first use, the functions pthread_cond_wait(), pthread_cond_timedwait(), pthread_cond_signal(), and pthread_cond_broadcast() ***branch into a slow path*** and cause the initialization of the condition.
>
> Due to this delayed initialization, the results of calling pthread_cond_destroy() on a condition variable that was initialized using static initialization and not used yet cause pthread_cond_destroy() to fail with teh EINVAL error.

What does it mean when they say **"branch into a slow path"**?
What it happening there?

Comment: I'd guess that it tests some flag indicating whether the `pthread_cond_t` object is initialized or not and performs the init if the flag indicates it's not done yet. Some sort of compiler optimization technique is used to make the code path where the object is already initialized execute without stalling the processor since it's more likely to be in that state for the program run (perhaps using something like gcc's `__builtin_expect()` functionality that Linux maps to the `likely()` and `unlikely()` macros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> branch into a slow path and cause the initialization of the condition.

Branching into a "slow" path probably means that additional code is called to perform (one-time) initialisation of the condition variable's 1st usage.

As this happens only once, the first usage of the condition takes longer than the following calls, hence it is "slower" than any upfollowing usage.